# Chamar funções de um controller na view _Layout.cshtml do ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um menu sendo carregado em uma Action de um controller. Já configurei a view dessa action no _ViewStart para ser o padrão do meu projeto. Mas essa view não está puxando nenhuma informação do comtroller. Já tentei por ViewBag, por Model e agora estou tentando por Session.

Páginas que são configuradas para serem o Layout padrão, não podem receber actions dos controllers?

Segue meu controller:

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    // GET: Menu
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Teste()
    {
        MenuDAO dao = new MenuDAO();
        string usuarioLogado = "diego";
        IList<Menu> menu = dao.MontaMenu(usuarioLogado);

        //ViewBag.Menu = menu;

        Session["teste"] = "Essa frase está vindo do controller";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Segue a minha view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}


@model IList<PortalAraguaina.Models.Menu>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Teste
        <p class="essa-eh-a-classe-de-teste">@Session["teste"]</p>
    </div>

    <div>@RenderBody()</div>
```

Comment: você pode chamar via javascript

Comment: mas afinal.. no título da pergunta você fala em chamar e nela você fala em puxar.. o que você quer fazer exatamente?

Comment: Quero apenas que a view carregue as informações que estão na action do controller

Comment: para retornar a sua lista para a view voce tem que fazer isso `return View(menu);`

Comment: Já tentei Vinicius, em todas as views eu faço assim, mas na view que coloquei como padrão do _Layout não funciona. Retorna null.

Comment: M. Bertolazo, como você chamaria via JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Para renderizar o resultado de uma action a partir de uma view (no seu caso a _Layout), use o helper Action.

Não precisa de ViewBag nem qualquer outro meio de transporte de dados.

Retorne direto o html da view:
`@Html.Action("Teste", "Menu");`